# Printer won't print

Tags: printing

I have a new HPEnvy 4500 printer. As soon as I connected it and turned it on it worked, and I printed two Ubuntu test pages. Then it stopped printing anything from Ubuntu although it will print or scan from XP.  what canI do?

Answer (score 1):

Try it with "hplip". Available on Ubuntu software center. This is support for HP printers.

If you know your printers' IP (assuming it's wireless), you can enter this in your browser to see if it is connected and try to adjust preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://localhost:631/.  This is the CUPS 1.7.2 site where you will manually register your printer.  When you get to the site, click on the Printers tab; you may very well see your printer listed here, but it may not have been registered automatically.  Weather you see it listed or not, click on the Administration tab and enter your printer information.  (My printer was listed when I clicked on the Printer tab, and it was also recognized by Ubuntu, but it still would not print because it was not registered automatically.)  After you finish entering your printer information, your printer may very well start working properly.  Make sure you are booted to Ubuntu and not Windows--if you are, in fact, double booting from the same computer.